# Regular Expression for finding Repeated Words

Tags: java, regex

```
**(?i)\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+**
```

I understand what each symbol means but when the symbols are combined...I can't figure out. The confusion part is (?:\s+\1\b)+. What does it mean??? Can you explain to me?? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Paste it into [http://regexr.com/](http://regexr.com/) and it'll explain it to you.

Comment: @moritzg thanks you!

Comment: @SebastianProske thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Individual parts of `(?:\s+\1\b)+` have the following meaning:

- `(?:...)` - a non-capturing group. It contains:
- `\s+` - a non-empty sequence of *white space* chars.
- `\1` - a backreference to capturing group #1 (`\b([a-z]+)\b`).
  It means that you want to have here just the same chars (the repeated word)
  which has been just captured.
- `\b` - a word boundary, in this case transition from *word area* to *space area*.

After the whole above group there is a `+` sign, meaning that you want to
match as many repeating words as possible.

Comment: thanks for your explaining.